# How to use Hazelcast with tomcat in eclipse

Tags: java, exception, hazelcast

I'm trying to run below mention and it is throwing an `NoClassDefFoundException`:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import com.hazelcast.core.Hazelcast;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class LoginUser
 */
@WebServlet("/loginUser")
public class LoginUser extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public LoginUser() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Map<String,String> map=Hazelcast.getMap("user");
        PrintWriter out=response.getWriter();
        String user=request.getParameter("user");
        String pwd=request.getParameter("pwd");
        if(map.containsKey(user))
        {
            if(pwd!=map.get(user));
            {
                out.write("please correct your password");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            out.write("please correct your username");
        }
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

}
```

**Stack trace:**

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [ifkaar.admin.LoginUser] in context with path [/IfkaarAdmin] threw exception [Servlet execution threw an exception] with root cause
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.hazelcast.core.Hazelcast
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1678)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1523)
    at ifkaar.admin.LoginUser.doGet(LoginUser.java:35)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:304)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:224)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:462)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:164)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:851)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:405)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:278)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:515)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:302)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Aug 4, 2011 12:51:46 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [ifkaar.admin.LoginUser] in context with path [/IfkaarAdmin] threw exception [Servlet execution threw an exception] with root cause
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/hazelcast/core/Hazelcast
    at ifkaar.admin.LoginUser.doGet(LoginUser.java:35)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:304)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:224)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:462)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:164)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:851)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:405)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:278)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:515)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:302)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Comment: BTW: You did forget to ask a question. The Hazelcast classes are not available at runtime. Did you place them in your `WEB-INF/lib`?

Comment: well i have placed hazelcast jar in WEB-INF/lib but still it throwing that exception ... it seems to me as the problem of eclipse build path. i need help ....

Comment: ok thanks its working now when i put jar into WEB-INF/lib.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need [hazelcast](http://findjar.com/jar/com/hazelcast/hazelcast/1.5.1/hazelcast-1.5.1.jar.html) library in your classpath at runtime. place this jar in `WEB-INF/lib`

Answer (score 0):

You can place the hazelcast library in either

1. In your WAR's classpath at runtime as explined in WEB-INF/lib (as
   explained by others) -or-
2. In the shared $CATALINA_HOME/lib area